# How HttpResponse is mapped back in case of dynamic IP?

Tags: web-applications, http, networking, tcp

1. I have dynamic IP provided by ISP.  Say IP is x
2. I type google.com in browser. Http request goes to google server
3. IP changes to Y.
4. How does http response comes back to my laptop/broswer when IP changed  from X to Y ?

Does google continue to send to X and NAT layer in b/w play the role of switching it from X to Y ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't. When your IP address changes to Y, the response never reaches your LAN.

So why don't you notice IP address changes?

1. Because it doesn't happen too frequently. At home, your IP should change at most once per day.
2. Because requests are very fast. Once you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after you typed “google.com,” the response reaches your PC in dozens of milliseconds. The risk for your IP address to change *exactly* within those milliseconds is pretty low.
3. Because of the retry mechanism. Some websites, as well as some browsers, silently retry several times before admitting to the user that they failed.

Comment: You said `Because it doesn't happen too frequently` But what about persistent connection like with http 1.1/websockets where multiple request and response are sent over same connection ?

Comment: If the IP address changes, your persistent connection is no longer persistent, is it?

Comment: The connection is closed, and a new one is opened it needed (i.e. it the browser decides to open a new connection). You can very easily test it yourself by switching from Wi-Fi to 3G/4G connection on your phone.